# Unable to set selected value in select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

```js
// inside controller

$scope.newEngagement.subType = 3;

$scope.engagementSubTypeList = [ 
{ "subTypeId": 1, "subTypeName": "value1" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 2, "subTypeName": "value2" },  
{ "subTypeId": 3, "subTypeName": "value3" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 4, "subTypeName": "value4" },
];
```

```html
<div class="col s12 m12 margin-top-2x" ng-show="isSubType">
        <label class="uppercase blue-grey-text text-darken-5 font-1-5x clear left">SELECT SUB TYPE </label>
        <select
                name="engagement_subtype"
                id="engagement_subtype"
                ng-model="newEngagement.subType"
                class="browser-default margin-top-x col s12 m8 clear">
            <option value="{{subTypeList.subTypeId}}"
                    selected="subTypeList.subTypeId == newEngagement.subType"
                    ng-repeat="subTypeList in engagementSubTypeList track by subTypeList.subTypeId ">
                {{subTypeList.subTypeName}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**According to that above code "value3" should be selected but not happen same as I am using materialize select box browser default class.**

Comment: I think you need to use ng-selected

Comment: I tried ng-selected but fail to make selected

Answer (score 1):

Can try this one using `ng-options` and assign `newEngagement.subType` from your `$scope.engagementSubTypeList` like bellow. that should work.

```
<div class="">
    <label class="uppercase">SELECT SUB TYPE </label>
    <select ng-options="subTypeList.subTypeId as subTypeList.subTypeName for subTypeList in engagementSubTypeList" ng-model="newEngagement.subType">
      <option value="">Select One</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

and controller

```
$scope.engagementSubTypeList = [ 
{ "subTypeId": 1, "subTypeName": "value1" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 2, "subTypeName": "value2" },  
{ "subTypeId": 3, "subTypeName": "value3" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 4, "subTypeName": "value4" },
];

$scope.newEngagement = {};
$scope.newEngagement.subType = $scope.engagementSubTypeList[2].subTypeId;
```

Comment: Tried but not woking that code hide the option field

Comment: hide because you used `ng-show="isSubType"` in  your parent `div` I don't know that logic so remove that and check again pls @GovindJha

Comment: ng-show logic was if scope value is ready then show the dropdown

Comment: check please this link https://plnkr.co/edit/SuFdlhKGvCmlhtjALXcH?p=preview

Comment: write, but problem only with materialize css framwork and I am using that framwork

Comment: Angular logic is correct. I think you may missed somewhere else otherwise it should render correctly. How can I help you? can check by remove all class to check is render or not without style. also check in page source is it render or not

Comment: Thanks bro for the conversation I find the mistake 
Actually ng-option worked I missed a class="browser-default margin-top-x col s12 m8 clear"  when adding ng-option 

now working with ng-option

but the point is In this project there are total 3 select box and all has ng-repeat and all are working fine 

finally thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<div class="col s12 m12 margin-top-2x">
<label class="uppercase blue-grey-text text-darken-5 font-1-5x clear left">SELECT SUB TYPE </label>
<select
name="engagement_subtype"
id="engagement_subtype"
ng-model="newEngagement.subType"
class="browser-default margin-top-x col s12 m8 clear">
<option value="{{subTypeList.subTypeId}}"
ng-selected="{{newEngagement.subType == subTypeList.subTypeId}}"
ng-repeat="subTypeList in engagementSubTypeList track by subTypeList.subTypeId ">
{{subTypeList.subTypeName}}
</option>
</select>
</div>

$scope.newEngagement = {};
$scope.newEngagement.subType = 2;//{"subTypeId":3};

$scope.engagementSubTypeList = [ 
{ "subTypeId": 1, "subTypeName": "value1" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 2, "subTypeName": "value2" },  
{ "subTypeId": 3, "subTypeName": "value3" }, 
{ "subTypeId": 4, "subTypeName": "value4" },
];
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9r0rtsL/8/)

My suggestion is to avoid the  ng-repeat in selection option. You will be use to [ng-option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), It is only a correct approch in angularjs.

Comment: tried but not working. my code is also correct. I think there is a silly mistake this time need a fresh eye to view this

Comment: Now I'm updating the answer. It's work fine to your requirement